# Installing ovirt hosted engine, failing on "The ipaddr filter requires python's netaddr be installed on the ansible controller" but netaddr installed

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, ovirt

Trying to install an ovirt hosted engine and getting the following:

```
host01 idiot_user # hosted-engine --deploy --4
[ INFO  ] Stage: Initializing
[ INFO  ] Stage: Environment setup
          During customization use CTRL-D to abort.
          Continuing will configure this host for serving as hypervisor and will create a local VM with a running engine.
          The locally running engine will be used to configure a new storage domain and create a VM there.
          At the end the disk of the local VM will be moved to the shared storage.
          Are you sure you want to continue? (Yes, No)[Yes]:

<many INFO messages redacted>

[ INFO  ] skipping: [localhost]
[ INFO  ] TASK [ovirt.ovirt.hosted_engine_setup : Parse host address resolution]
[ ERROR ] fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The ipaddr filter requires python's netaddr be installed on the ansible controller"}
[ ERROR ] Failed to execute stage 'Closing up': Failed executing ansible-playbook
[ INFO  ] Stage: Clean up
[ INFO  ] Cleaning temporary resources
[ INFO  ] TASK [ovirt.ovirt.hosted_engine_setup : Execute just a specific set of steps]

<more redacted for space, no errors>

[ INFO  ] TASK [ovirt.ovirt.hosted_engine_setup : include_tasks]
[ INFO  ] ok: [localhost]
[ INFO  ] TASK [ovirt.ovirt.hosted_engine_setup : Remove local vm dir]
[ ERROR ] fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "argument 'path' is of type <class 'NoneType'> and we were unable to convert to path: 'None' is not a string and conversion is not allowed"}
[ ERROR ] Failed to execute stage 'Clean up': Failed executing ansible-playbook
[ INFO  ] Generating answer file '/var/lib/ovirt-hosted-engine-setup/answers/answers-20240224160431.conf'
[ INFO  ] Stage: Pre-termination
[ INFO  ] Stage: Termination
[ ERROR ] Hosted Engine deployment failed: please check the logs for the issue, fix accordingly or re-deploy from scratch.
          Log file is located at /var/log/ovirt-hosted-engine-setup/ovirt-hosted-engine-setup-20240224160108-nz5cgz.log

host01 idiot_user # netaddr
IPython (http://ipython.scipy.org/) not found!
host01 idiot_user #
```

yet netaddr is installed. It however, complains that IPython is not found. Yet ipython is installed.

I am in a twisty maze of python all alike.

Any help would be appreciated.

iii

tried figuring out how python looks for ipython to no avail.